# Resource Not Found | MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when trying to update 'wallet.beans' value using subtract & $set operator I get the following error:

```
err CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "{ '$subtract': [ '$agency.total_balance', { '$multiply': [Array] } ] }" (type Object) at path "wallet.beans"
at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4638:21)
at model.Query.mongoose.Query.exec (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\src\api\utils\cache.js:22:21)
at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4737:15)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
messageFormat: undefined,
stringValue: "{ '$subtract': [ '$agency.total_balance', { '$multiply': [Array] } ] }",
kind: 'Number',
value: { '$subtract': [ '$agency.total_balance', [Object] ] },
path: 'wallet.beans',
reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
```

```
assert.ok(!isNaN(val))

  at castNumber (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\number.js:28:10)
  at SchemaNumber.cast (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\number.js:380:12)    
  at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1135:12)
  at SchemaNumber.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1567:15)
  at SchemaNumber.castForQuery (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\number.js:434:14)
  at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\Ahmed Magdy\Desktop\source_code\node_modules\mongoose\lib\sc    generatedMessage: true,
code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',    actual: false,
expected: true,    operator: '=='
```

},
valueType: 'Object'
}

my code:

```
let updateUserWalletBalance = await User.updateMany(
                {
                    'agency.id': agencyId,
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        'wallet.beans': {
                            $subtract: [
                                '$agency.total_balance',
                                {
                                    $multiply: [
                                        '$agency.total_balance',
                                        -0.1,
                                    ],
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                }
            );
```

Comment: _"CastError: Cast to Number failed for value"_ : Maybe you have a non-numeric data where a number is expected in your update's arithmetic operation.

Comment: could you check the code, and correct it!!

Comment: It could be in your database data; you need to look in the documents being read for the update operation. Or, it could be that you need to use Updates With Aggregation Pipeline  for your update - as you are using a field value in the calculation.

Comment: I can use aggregation pipelines, but I can't save the output of this pipelines

Comment: Refer this: [Updates with Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)